# Room database onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am working on Room database and trying to insert **list of items**(eg. list of Quotes which contains author name and a quote in my case).

Following is the code I am using:

```
// view model
BaseApp.daoInstance?.appDao()?.insertQuotes(response!!)

// dao
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertQuotes(listData: MutableList<Quote>)
```

When I try to insert the same data again, it always inserts as a new data instead of **replacing** with the current items.

I have researched a lot for this **OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE** but could not find any proper answer.

Is there anyone facing the same issue and found solution or am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you in advance...!!!

Comment: Conflict means if it has a same id then it will replace that data for particular id. I used to use room database with _OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE_ as always. It works fine.

Comment: But how can we achieve this conflict as the data is not inserted yet? Ideally id will be generated once the data is inserted then do you have any idea what could be done in my case?

Comment: Show me the code for data insertion.

Comment: BaseApp.daoInstance?.appDao()?.insertQuotes(response!!)

Comment: Before you insert data, are you use nuke table or delete by id before insert data?

Comment: No, I am doing nothing as I don't want to delete my older data. I am just fetching data from the API and inserting into database. Now, while inserting the data I want to check for duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193672/discussion-between-piyush-and-aanal-mehta).

Comment: Looks like you are autogenerating your primary key ids. In this case duplicate data will be added as for room this is a new data

Comment: Could you add the definition of your `Quote` entity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Room, will not check and compare if you have the quote already in the DB.
What it will do is look if the primary key already exists in the DB if it does, Room will replace all old data with the new one.

In your case, you are not specifying an ID so the DB is generating a unique one for you.
What you should do is create a `Query` that will search for this quote in the DB something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * from quote_table WHERE author = :author AND quote = :quote")
List<Quote> getQuoteByAuthorAndQuote(string author, string quote);
```

This should return a list with a single quote if one is found and empty if it does not exist.

If you would like to override the old one just update the data in the Quote POJO and insert it to the DB using Room.

Comment: Yes. That was an alternative I have done in my code. Now I got the answer that room database will replace data based on primary key and not the content value. Thank you!

Comment: @Aanal Mehta If this answer helped you please mark it as answered so it will help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I searched

Comment: Not a great solution. Why check for duplicates manually when you can just make the quote a unique key and let Room do the replace for you with OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to index your main column and mark it as unique?

```
@Index(value = {"quote"}, unique = true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to search for your unique or primary key and compare then replace, while in your case you're not defining an ID so it will generate a unique one for you, so it won't even compare and will consider any item as a new one.

Write a new query and function to solve this issue.

Answer (score -7):

When I had same problem, changes in imports did the trick, added following import:

`import androidx.room.*;`